# Триггер, который запретит добавлять автора, если количество авторов больше 7

Tags: sql, sql-server, триггер

Триггер, который при добавлении или изменении авторов публикации запретит добавление автора, если у публикации более 7 авторов.

Триггер не выполняет свою задачу. В чем может быть проблема?

```
CREATE TRIGGER Q
ON АвторПубликаций
FOR INSERT, UPDATE
AS
IF EXISTS(
SELECT Публикации.Код_публикации,COUNT(id_автора)
FROM INSERTED,Публикации
WHERE INSERTED.Код_публикации=Публикации.Код_публикации
GROUP BY Публикации.Код_публикации
HAVING COUNT(id_автора)>7
) 
BEGIN
ROLLBACK TRANSACTION 
PRINT 'Нельзя добавить еще автора'
END
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: НИКОГДА не используйте триггеры. Это ни как не обрабатываемое поведение системы. Если есть возможность обработать ограничение на уровне кода программы, которая делает вставку - сделайте там. Тот кто будет поддерживать систему после автора триггера потратит массу времени что бы понять почему не работает insert...

Answer (score 1):

```
IF EXISTS(
  SELECT COUNT(АвторПубликаций.id_автора)
    FROM (SELECT Код_публикации FROM INSERTED GROUP BY Код_публикации) u
      JOIN АвторПубликаций ON АвторПубликаций.Код_публикации=u.Код_публикации
  GROUP BY u.Код_публикации
  HAVING COUNT(АвторПубликаций.id_автора)>7)
```